# Can I use a custom view as a NSSplitView's divider?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nssplitview

I want to use a taller (27pt) view as the divider for a `NSSplitView` which is vertically-stacked (`splitView.isVertical = false`). **Is there an intended way to do this?** If not, **is there a common hack?**

I was thinking of using a thin divider and listening for mouse drags in the custom view, and using those to programmatically change the divider's location. **Is this a valid approach?**

Comment: Maybe the delegate has some methods to do this? Did you check?

Comment: @Willeke [`NSSplitViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssplitviewdelegate) contains zero functions which return a `NSView` or similar

Comment: How about `splitView(_:effectiveRect:forDrawnRect:ofDividerAt:)` and `splitView(_:additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAt:)`?

Comment: @Willeke Those are rectangles (which I tried out and only seem to affect the tracking area, not the size). I want to put a whole view in there.

Answer (score 3):

An approach that doesn't require listening to mouse drags or any active updating of the view is to use auto layout:

**1.** Override `dividerThickness` to return your ideal thickness.

**2.** Override `dividerColor` to return clear if your custom view is not opaque and if you don't want the default grey showing through.

If you have a minimum deployment target of 10.11 or later:

**3a.** Set `arrangesAllSubviews` to NO on the split view and then add the custom divider view as a subview of the split view. (without setting `arrangesAllSubviews` to NO, adding the custom divider view would add it as a split pane)

Otherwise, if your minimum deployment target is < 10.11 (or you otherwise cannot set `arrangesAllSubviews` to NO):

**3b.** Add a your custom divider as a subview of the container of the split view, but making sure it's higher in subview/z-order

**4.** Add constraints to position that view where the divider would be, e.g.:

```
let constraints = [dividerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topPane.bottomAnchor),
                   dividerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topPane.bottomAnchor),
                   dividerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: splitView.leadingAnchor),
                   dividerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: splitView.trailingAnchor)]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Auto layout will take care of updating the position of the divider view when the user drags.

Comment: Hi, do you know what does arrangesAllSubviews do? My app is crashing with that on, but with that off i get a warning that is off