# How do I implement a custom divider in NSSplitViewController?

Tags: appkit, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement a custom divider in an `NSSplitViewController` subclass. I want something similar to what Xcode has between the code editing area and the console area.

Ideally, I'd like to use SwiftUI for the internals of the divider itself.

I tried subclassing `NSSplitView` and overriding its `dividerThickness` property. That worked. What I can't figure out is how to actually use a custom view for the divider contents itself.

I'm looking at `drawDivider(in rect: NSRect)` which gives me an `NSRect` to work with, but I'm not sure if I can use the rect to "draw" a custom view.

I also tried this:

```swift
class FooController: NSSplitViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        splitView.arrangesAllSubviews = false
        //...
        splitView.addArrangedSubview(dividerView)
        super.loadView()
    }
}
```

But that results in an exception: `A SplitView managed by a SplitViewController cannot have its arranged views modified`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right path? Should I even be subclassing `NSSplitView`? Or am I supposed to subclass `NSSplitViewController`? Or both? Or am I supposed to completely bypass `NSSplitViewController` and just use `NSSplitView` directly? Or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a custom view as a NSSplitView's divider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643604/can-i-use-a-custom-view-as-a-nssplitviews-divider)

Comment: @Willeke, I saw that answer. It lead me to the experiments I already tried, but it doesn't answer which classes I subclass and how it all connects together. That's why I couldn't make it work.